# How do I select the average of the results of a MYSQL subquery within another query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this query I am trying to run, but it keeps failing. Anyone have any idea as to what may be going wrong?

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(`date1`,`date2`) AS `date_difference_value`,  
    AVG(`difference`) FROM (
        SELECT DATEDIFF(`date1`,`date2`) AS `difference`
        FROM `datetable`
        WHERE MONTH(`date2`) = '08'
            AND `date1` <> '0000-00-00'
            AND `date2` <> '0000-00-00'
    ) AS `average`
FROM `datetable`
WHERE MONTH(`date2`) = '08'
```

Comment: What is the error?  What are you trying to do?  Why do you compare numeric values to strings?

Comment: You have two `FROM` clauses in your query.

Comment: The error is: #1054 - Unknown column 'date1' in 'field list'

Comment: I am trying to select the average of the output from that subquery as well as the rest of the values from the parent query

Comment: You need to join the results of the subquery to `datetable`.  There's not enough information in your SQL to tell how you should do that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to calculate the month average and then output that on each row together with the date1 and date2 details.

To me most obvious error in your existing query is that you have 2 FROM clauses

```
SELECT *
 , DATEDIFF(`date1`, `date2`) AS `date_difference_value`
 , AVG(`difference`)
FROM (
       SELECT DATEDIFF(`date1`, `date2`) AS `difference`
       FROM `datetable`
       WHERE MONTH(`date2`) = '08' AND `date1` != '0000-00-00' AND `date2` < '0000-00-00'
      ) AS `average`
FROM `datetable`
WHERE MONTH(`date2`) = '08'
```

If my guesses about your requirements are correct then the following may suit:

```
SELECT
   `datetable`.*
 , DATEDIFF(`date1`, `date2`) AS `date_difference_value`
 , `average`.`avg_difference`
FROM `datetable`
CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(`date1`, `date2`)) AS `avg_difference`
     FROM `datetable`
     WHERE MONTH(`date2`) = 8
     ) AS `average`
WHERE MONTH(`date2`) = 8
```

Notes:

1. the subquery returns just a single value hence the cross join will not multiply the number of rows
2. MONTH() returns an integer so MONTH(`date2`) = '08' would not be true
3. If a date returns 8 as the month then it cannot also be '0000-00-00' at the same time
4. I can't be sure if you need "AND `date1` <> '0000-00-00'" (you might need it I just cannot be sure if you do). Perhaps you need **AND `date1` IS NOT NULL**